# Python multithreading broken

Tags: python, multithreading

I wanted to start learning about threading in python so I grabbed myself a tutorial and started reading and coding. The following code is what I came up with.
I created a function wait that is suppoesed to print out "Waiting started" and then go to sleep for 3 seconds befor printing out "Waiting ended". I created a main function, where I create and start the thread t1. After the thread t1 started I would expect "Meanwile..." to be printed out. However the thread behaves like I initialized it with .run().

Can someone explain this behavior to me and maybe give me a solution how to fix this?

```
import threading
from time import sleep


def wait():
    print("Waiting started")
    sleep(3)
    print("Waiting ended")


def main():
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=wait())
    t1.start()
    print("Meanwhile...")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I tried .start() and .run() and for some reason in both cases the output is the same, even though they have a completely diffrent functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem is that you have written:

```py
t1 = threading.Thread(target=wait())
```

When you need to write:

```py
t1 = threading.Thread(target=wait)
```

You need the function without parentheses because the former *calls* `wait()` and passes what it *returns* (nothing) into `threading.Thread`, while the latter passes the *function* into `threading.Thread`, so that it can be called later.

Full code:

```py
import threading
from time import sleep


def wait():
    print("Waiting started")
    sleep(3)
    print("Waiting ended")


def main():
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=wait)
    t1.start()
    print("Meanwhile...")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is that you call the function `wait` in line `t1 = threading.Thread(target=wait())`

The target argument has to be set to the name of the function without brackets. So `t1 = threading.Thread(target=wait)` should work.